# Internal link to a hyperlink heading

Tags: hyperlink, org-mode, heading

In a document, I'd like to create an internal link. That works [as expected](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Internal-links.html#Internal-links) on regular links. But when the heading is itself a hyperlink, that doesn't work. How *ought* one accomplish this?

```
Trying to link to [[Heading1]] and [[???]]

* Heading1 

These are some contents.

* [[http://example.com][Heading2]]

These are some more contents.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the second heading and do `C-c l` to store the link (assuming you have set up the key binding as suggested in the manual: if not, just say `M-x org-store-link RET`).

Then go to the place where you want to insert the link and do `C-c C-l` (or `M-x org-insert-link RET`).

Now try your new link: it worked fine for me.

For the record, this is what the working result looks like:

```
Trying to link to [[Heading1]] and [[*\[\[http://example.com\]\[Heading2\]\]][Heading2]]

* Heading1 

These are some contents.

* [[http://example.com][Heading2]]

These are some more contents.
```

Comment: Ah. Perfect. It was the escaping that I needed to know about.